# How to associate my app to a file type in Android

Tags: android

I'm working on a music player app and am trying to get it to launch and play the selected song when it's selected in a file explorer. My app shows up in the app list when a music file is clicked, and even launches when selected. However, my playSong function is apparently not set at the action because no song plays. Here are the relevant portions of my manifest.xml. Can someone point me in the right direction?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="my.app.com"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="7"
        android:targetSdkVersion="15" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MyMusicPlayer"
            android:excludeFromRecents="true"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoDisplay" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <data android:mimeType="audio/*"/>
    </intent-filter>
            </activity>

        <service android:name="MusicPlayer" >
        </service>
        <service android:name=".SongListActivity" >
        </service>s

    </application>

</manifest>
```

Thanks

Comment: Post the code for `MyMusicPlayer`, at least `onCreate()`

Comment: I don't play a song in onCreate(). All I do is initialize my media player, set all of the controls on the view and set the album art to the first song in the list. Under normal circumstances, when starting the application, the song will be displayed...but the user will have to play it or select another song first. It doesn't play be default.

However, the song that is selected in the file explorer isn't even displayed in the UI when I launch my app that way. It just loads the first song in the list like normal. Is there a way to pass the song info to onCreate() if the app is launched that way?

Comment: The song that the user selected to be opened with your app will be available through the `Intent` that your `MyMusicPlayer` activity receives. You can call `getIntent()` pretty much anywhere from within the activity and retrieve its contents. You're probably going to be interested in the result of [`getIntent().getData()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#getData%28%29). It'll be a `Uri` that points to the relevant content (`file:///` in the case of a file stored on the device).

Comment: Ok, that make sense...thanks. My scenario is actually a bit more complex though. The main activity....MyMusicPlayer just launches a custom class that extends the Service class. Essentially, my app has no activities in a traditional sense. I guess I would just need to access getIntent().getData() from the main activity, then pass it to my Player service as an extra param in the "launch" function. Would that be the right way to do it? Thanks again.

Comment: @user2167861: Yes, that's pretty much the gist of it. In the scenario desribed above, your activity will be nothing more than a pass-through to get the intent data to the service, which is totally fine.